# Incorrect Code for an R dataset after reading file xlsx

Tags: r

So I had a dataset that I had to read in the form of xlsx. So I did the downloading of the package and “library(xlsx)”. I managed to get the file open but when I wanted to isolate columns 2 to 4 using the code “M_Data = Myfilename[2:4], it tells me that the function could not be found or object not found. I’m not sure how to fix this.

![The exercise] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zkb0.jpg)
I tried to upload my errors but could not.
My errors:
Error in RNA_Seq_Results[2:4] could not find function “RNA_Seq_Results”

Comment: `Myfilename[ , 2:4]`?

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately, it gave me the same error. Error: object “file name” not found.

Comment: please include the steps necessary to reproduce your problem in the code. Without it, we would just be guessing. You could include a sample data set such as `x = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])`

Comment: I apologize for that. I should have included the problem first but I edited to include it now.

Comment: Did you save your dataframe after opening the file with `RNA_Seq_Results  <- readxl::read_xlsx("your_file.xlsx")`?

Comment: I tried this as well but it’s not working either. I used the function save and write.table as it was suggested by our professor. I sent an email to him but he hasn’t responded.

Comment: On a sidenote, step b of the exercise is considered bad practice in R. `for` + `if` for a subsetting action is both slower and harder to read than *vectorized* alternatives. For this exercise `df[df$Treatment == "P", 2:4]` is preferable.

Comment: I apologize for that. This is for my biostatistics class and my first time learning r so this is the second exercise he gave us which I was confused on.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what your problem is since I can't see what it looks like on your end, but you can usually read excel files with the readxl library by using `read_xlsx` or `read_xls`. Make sure your directory in R is correct. An example is shown below:

```
library(readxl)
read_xlsx("file.xlsx")
```

To give you a data frame since I can't see it here, you can recreate whats in that picture with this code:

```
#### Create all variables: ####

Sex <- c("M","F","M","F",
         "M","F","M","F",
         "M","F","M","F")

Stage <- c("I","II", "II", "I", 
           "II", "II", "I", "II", 
           "II", "I", "II", "II")

Treatment <- c("A","A","A","A",
               "B","B","B","B",
               "P","P","P","P")

Myc <- c(2343,
         457,
         4593,
         9035,
         3450,
         3524,
         958,
         1053,
         8674,
         3424,
         463,
         5105)

datarows <- c("sample1",
           "sample2",
           "sample3",
           "sample4",
           "sample5",
           "sample6",
           "sample7",
           "sample8",
           "sample9",
           "sample10",
           "sample11",
           "sample12")

#### Create dataframe with variables ####

df <- data.frame(datarows,
       Sex,
          Stage,
          Treatment,
          Myc)
```

Which will give you this if you simply enter `df`:

```
   datarows Sex Stage Treatment  Myc
1   sample1   M     I         A 2343
2   sample2   F    II         A  457
3   sample3   M    II         A 4593
4   sample4   F     I         A 9035
5   sample5   M    II         B 3450
6   sample6   F    II         B 3524
7   sample7   M     I         B  958
8   sample8   F    II         B 1053
9   sample9   M    II         P 8674
10 sample10   F     I         P 3424
11 sample11   M    II         P  463
12 sample12   F    II         P 5105
```

Edit: One other thing, you can also just load excel files with dropdowns in R if you are having issues with the code way. I've shown where to do this below:

[image]

Comment: read.xlsx should be read_xlsx

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for commenting. Ive edited it.